# String.Replace only replaces first occurrence of matched string. How to replace *all* occurrences?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

Coming from other programming languages, `String.replace()` typically replaces all occurrences of matching strings. However, that is not the case with *javascript/typescript*. I found a number of solutions on the web with *javascript* utilizing regex. I immediately had issues with this solution because of special characters. I suspect there is a way to correct this with regex, but I am not a regex expert. As many have done before me, I created my own method.

Perhaps there are ways to improve performance by making use of a custom `StringBuilder()` class. I welcome any thoughts.

```
public static Replace = function (originalString: string, oldValue: string, newValue: string, ignoreCase: boolean = false) {
    //
    // if invalid data, return the original string
    //
    if ((originalString == null) || (oldValue == null) || (newValue == null) || (oldValue.length == 0) )
        return (originalString);
    //
    // do text replacement
    //
    var dest = "";        
    var source: string = originalString;
    if (ignoreCase) 
    {
        source = source.toLocaleLowerCase();
        oldValue = oldValue.toLowerCase();
    }
    //
    // find first match
    //
    var StartPos = 0;
    var EndPos = source.indexOf(oldValue, StartPos);
    var Skip = (EndPos >= 0) ? EndPos - StartPos : source.length-StartPos;   
    //
    // while we found a matched string
    //     
    while (EndPos > -1) {
        //
        // copy original string skipped segment
        //
        if (Skip > 0) dest += originalString.substr(StartPos, Skip);            
        //
        // copy new value
        //
        dest += newValue;
        //
        // skip over old value
        //
        StartPos = EndPos + oldValue.length;
        //
        // find next match
        //
        EndPos = source.indexOf(oldValue, StartPos);
        Skip = (EndPos >= 0) ? EndPos - StartPos : source.length - StartPos;    
    }
    //
    // append the last skipped string segment from original string
    //
    if (Skip > 0) dest += originalString.substr(StartPos, Skip);   

    return dest;
}
```

In order to add support to this method to the `string` class I added the following code:

```
interface String { EZReplace(oldValue: string, newValue: string, ignorCase?: boolean): string; }

String.prototype.EZReplace = function (oldValue: string, newValue: string, ignorCase: boolean = false) {
return EZUtil.Replace(this, oldValue, newValue, ignorCase);}
```

....After re-viewing other posts, I modified the code to use regular expressions. It would be interesting to execute performance tests.

```
 public static Replace = function (originalString: string, oldValue: string, newValue: string, ignoreCase: boolean = false) {
    //
    // if invalid data, return the original string
    //
    if ((originalString == null) || (oldValue == null) || (newValue == null) || (oldValue.length == 0))
        return (originalString);
    //
    // set search/replace flags
    //
    var Flags: string = (ignoreCase) ? "gi" : "g";
    //
    // apply regex escape sequence on pattern (oldValue)
    //
    var pattern = oldValue.replace(/[-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
    //
    // replace oldValue with newValue
    //
    var str = originalString.replace(new RegExp(pattern, Flags), newValue);
    return (str);
}
```

Comment: Have you already checked this post ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, among many others. However, after revisiting it, I have a better understanding on how the regular expression was being used. I modified the code above to reflect it. For me, it is a more concise answer. Perhaps it might help someone else.

Answer (score 87):

> In typescript, String.Replace only replaces first occurrence of matched string. Need String.replaceAll() method

There is nothing special to TypeScript here ([after all TypeScript is just JavaScript with type annotations](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html)). JavaScript `string.replace` only replaces the first instance if given a string. Only way to get replace all is to use a `regex` with `/g` modifier.

Alternatively I just do:

```
somestring.split('oldString').join('newString');
```

Comment: Yes, the String.split().join() method is short and sweet. However, it is not possible to perform case insensitive search/replace. The first time I used the regex with the /g modifier, it generated an invalid pattern for regular expression during code execution. I needed to include the escape sequences to the pattern. 

`var pattern = oldValue.replace(/[-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");`

That is why I like to include the entire function in my example. The procedure is simple and short enough to allow.

Comment: Love that split join stuff!

Comment: Just as a reference, here the TypeScript replace call using regex: `myString.replace(/oldString/g, 'newString);`

Comment: Regex fails when you have to replace special characters ( '[', ']' )

Comment: @JohanAspeling It need not fail. You can always escape speacial chars like `( '\[', '\]' )`

Answer (score 11):

In my case I did like this in TypeScript.

```
this.mystr= this.mystr.replace(new RegExp('class="dec-table"', 'g'), 'class="copydec-table"');
```

Credits to [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I'm using Node 12+. And there is no `.replaceAll()` for Node (Check the [Browser Compatibility on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)).

But my solution is using Regex(/g) with `.replace()`. The key is using `/g`.

```js
const s = `[People,Contracts,Facilities]`;
// My case was to remove the `[` and `]`
// So the key is using `/g`
const res = s.replace(/\[/g, '').replace(/\]/g, '');
```